# javafx checklistree output: the term inter comma

Tags: javafx

```
for (CheckBoxTreeItem<String> treeItem : treeItems) {
     if (treeItem.isSelected()) {
         if (treeItem.getValue() != null) {
             konular = konular + treeItem.getValue();
         }          
    }         
}

System.out.println(konular);
```

hi, this code for checktreeviews ,treelist sample1 sample2...

I have any choice, output: nullSample3Sample4

I want: sample3, sample4

Comment: How is `konular` declared?

Comment: private String konular = null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java 8 way:

```
String konular = treeItems
    .stream()
    .map(TreeItem::getValue)
    .filter(value -> value != null)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your variable like this:

```
String konular = "";
```

I believe it is currently turning `null` into a string when you add the first new string, and thus you end up with it starting with "null".

---

To add the comma, you could do something like this:

```
for (CheckBoxTreeItem<String> treeItem : treeItems) {
    if (treeItem.isSelected()) {
        if (treeItem.getValue() != null) {
            if(konular!=""){
                konular = konular + ", ";
            }
            konular = konular + treeItem.getValue();
        }          
    }         
}
```

I'm sure it's not the cleanest way, but it should do the trick.

Comment: ty, (the important part of this :) put a comma between the words ?

Comment: @anyQues Added to the answer to show how you could put in the comma in.